# “How to know if ‘server is a live or not’ without getting php error in socket_connet”

Tags: error-handling, codeigniter-3, phpwebsocket

I am working on a tare web application based on the codeigniter-3 framework, which I have to connect to a websocket, everything works fine if the server is online, but if the server is offline, a php error occurs.

I used exec function in php, this allows me to ping the server and based on the return packet loss, this determine if the server is on or not. But sometimes it wont work. It allows it to pass, even if server is off, this have a chance of 1/20 to happen (this static is based only on experimental).

```php
$host = "192.168.1.100"; 
$port = 6001;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$suck = socket_connect($sock, $host, $port) or die("error: could not connect to host\n");
$tare = socket_read($sock, 1024);
$tare = trim($tare);
$tar_array = explode(" ", $tare);
for ($i=1; $i < 16 ; $i++) 
{ 
  $real_tare = $real_tare + intval($tar_array[$i]);
}
echo $real_tare;
```

I don't want the huge error message, but a small error_handler saying server down just a small one as i wrote, showing `err lan`, instead of the php error that stop all the app.
(PS. I couldn't provide image, or links due to my low reputation.)

Answer (score 0):

[socket_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php) aka `$suck` will be false if the connection wasn't made. Always in programming try something and check the error rather than looking for alive mechanisms (like ping).

Don't read `socket_read` without checking `$suck` is true first.

Use the `$suck` to branch to your smaller `error_handler` before a `socket_read` happens.

Comment: thank you @danblack for your answer and sorry for my late reply, so in order to be more explicit, you are right about all what you did say with socket_read, but my problem is socket_connect, it send a php error wich is not suitable, and took so much time to load the page.
this is the code that i use.

```php

$host = "192.168.1.100"; 
$port = 6001;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(socket_connect($sock, $host, $port)){
        echo "alive";
        tare = socket_read($sock, 1024);
 $tare = trim($tare)';

}else{
 echo "dead";
 }
```